# MacOS 10.15 SDK don't add LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX to binaries when used with SDK 10.15

Tags: c++, xcode, clang

MacOS 10.15 SDK don't add LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX to binaries when used with SDK 10.15.

And because of this Apple don't allow submit Mac Catalyst framework without "LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX" inside the binary.

To reproduce it you can use:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ hello.cpp -o myapp -mmacosx-version-min=10.9
```

And check with:

```
otool -l myapp | grep LC_VERSION
```

The output is:

```
cmd LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX
```

But when i change SDK version to `10.15` the `LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX` information don't exists.

How can i solve it?

Thanks.